# Can I map a @OneToMany relationship with JPA with an H2 in memory entity and an SQLServer entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities, one in H2 in memory database, and another persisted in SQL Server, and I need to map a OneToMany. When I do this, receive this error: "caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ENTITY-1 references an unknown entity: ENTITY-2".

```
Entity-1 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity1")
    private Set<Entity2> entity2;

    public Set<Entity2> getEntity2() {
        return entity2;
    }

Entity-2
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "identity1")
  private Entity1 entity1;
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible to map different databases. It's possible to map different schemas inside the same DB, but not different DB engines. Can you move everything to SQL Server? Having to use 2 DBs smells like a bad hack.

Answer (score 0):

Your JPA implementation can't map two entities in differente databases, because the mapping is used to generate sql request executed against that one database (there is nothing like cross db sql join request). also you get the exception because the inner entitymanager (or hibernate session if using hibernate) is only managing the entities attached to it. and each entitymanager/session can only instantiate a single database connection.

One solution to your probleme is to do it on two separate request and setting it mannualy or using a simple mapper like jmapper (not an orm). dont forget to put the two attributes to transient (@Transient) so the orm ignores it.